# Accessing ElasticSearch API on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

AWS recommends using its SDKs (such as `boto3`) or command-line tools to configure an ElasticSearch cluster.

However, some ElasticSearch API endpoints are not exposed in AWS APIs (e.g. `_cat/shards`).
Even some AWS support documents (such as [this one on cluster rebalancing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/es-rebalance-uneven-shards/)) seem to make direct request to the cluster API.

The trouble is: such requests need to be authenticated using AWS4Auth (only certain IAM roles have permissions to write to ElasticSearch, in my setup) – and even AWS [recommends against](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) making manually creating signed HTTP requests because it's such a pain.

**My question is:** do I need to manually create signed HTTP requests against my ES cluster in order to manage it, or is there an easier way that I've missed?

Comment: You can use [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) which is popular third party library for making signed requests to IAM protected API gateway, ES or other resources. Have you considered that?

Comment: I did not know about that one – seems like a good one to use. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The proposed solution is to use third party [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth):

> This package allows you to authenticate to AWS with Amazon's signature version 4 signing process with the python requests library.

The [example](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth#elasticsearch-py-client-usage-example) of its use for ElasticSearch is:

```
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

es_host = 'search-service-foobar.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'
auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key='YOURKEY',
                       aws_secret_access_key='YOURSECRET',
                       aws_host=es_host,
                       aws_region='us-east-1',
                       aws_service='es')

# use the requests connection_class and pass in our custom auth class
es_client = Elasticsearch(host=es_host,
                          port=80,
                          connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
                          http_auth=auth)
print es_client.info()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding this [AWS doc on request signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html) for AWS ElasticSearch. It clearly shows that the intended approach is to use scripts, using the HTTP client of choice for the language.

As Marcin mentioned in hist answer, [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) is one choice to simplifiy this in Python